# Adding object into array and changing property of other objects in that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How can I at the same time add this object into an array and change property `popup` to `false` to every other object (if there is any) in that same array?

```
 this.setState({
            map: {
                ...this.state.map,
                areas: this.state.map.areas.concat({
                    coords: [evt.nativeEvent.layerX, evt.nativeEvent.layerY, 15],
                    popup: true,
                })
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in the same time, but you could use `Object.assign` method and `map` in order to set the `popup` property to `false` and then just `concat` the *new* item.

```
areas: this.state.map.areas.map(item => Object.assign(item, {popup: false})).concat({
   coords: [evt.nativeEvent.layerX, evt.nativeEvent.layerY, 15],
   popup: true,
})
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!